# Help with subtracting from a group total in a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, grouping

What i am trying to do is create a list where i can add entries that staff received for Time Off Awards. In my organization time off awards can not go over 80 hours yearly. I have created a list view that groups the awards by staff name and then totals up how many hours they received. Basically the issue i am having is trying to find a way to subtract 80 hours from the total of time of hours in a group. I feel like there should be a easy way to do this. I have sharepoint designer if this is something that needs to be done using that. I am using SharePoint 2010.

Thank you,

Desperate for an answer

Comment: Try searching other Q&A on this site - try using this link to look for a formula that would work for you, one which uses calculated columns: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column-formula

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view page that filters or even groups by "group". Have that view turn on the totals feature "SUM" under the column "Hours". Then, create some javascript that takes the total value from the "Totals" view feature and subtracts 80.

some psuedo code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var totalhours = document.getElementsByTagName("nobr").innerText.split('=')[1];
    var minuseighty = int.parse(totalhours) - 80;
    document.getElementsByTagName("nobr").innerText = "Remaining=" + minuseighty;

});
```

Comment: unfortunetly I do not know much about code. Is there an easier way to do this? I made the new view, made a group and summed up the group using totals. The column I need to 80 hours to be deducted from is called Remaining Hours. Is there a way you can tell me what the code would be and explain how to copy it into SharePoint Designer to get it to work? I am so frustrated been trying to get this to work for day.

Comment: Make a CEWP above or below the list view webpart for the view. Then add the code above using "Edit Source" in the ribbon